# How do i convert this memoization code to dynamic programming (minimum coin change problem)

Tags: python, dynamic, memoization

```
def coinchange(amountofchange):
    if mem[amountofchange]==-1:
        if amountofchange==0:
            mem[amountofchange] = 0
        else:
            m = amountofchange
            for i in range(len(coin)):
                if coin[i]<=amountofchange:
                    x = 1+coin(amountofchange-coin[i])
                    m = min(m,x)
            mem[amountofchange] = m
    return mem[amountofchange]
```

I can memoize but cannot find a way to do it dynamically